# Will exporting a database using MySQL Workbench cause downtime on server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using Workbench to export a database stored on my hoting providers server, will the server experience any downtime whilst I am exporting the data?

The only reason I ask is because when I back up my local SQL database my server needs to be switched offline for it to work.

All comments will be much appreciated.

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it will not cause a downtime, unless your server has really low resources (in which case you should find a better hosting). Seriously though, nothing bad will happen.

Also I can hardly imagine why you need to disable your localhost for backup... Workbench uses mysqldump for exports and this in turn needs MySQL to be online...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't have the rep to up vote but will mark it as an answer as soon as i can (10mins)